# Cant change the order of Sitecore presentation items - Sitecore.NET 6.6.0 (rev. 130404)

Tags: sitecore

I am looking at a content item with many renderings.

I need to move one of the rendering down so it show lower on the page.

I can move it in the Edit presentation settings but as soon as I click ok, the order remains unchanged.

Note, it does work sometimes but is intermittent.

I have looked in the logs and nothing seems bad apart from this:

```
1032 11:20:45 WARN Long running operation: renderContentEditor pipeline[id={E23237A3-1FEB-4E9A-AEB6-543807ED6CAD}]
```

I feel this might be a Sitecore bug.

Has anyone experienced this before?

Comment: Can you try to change the order using raw values of the property and see if you can change it that way?

Comment: Out of curiousity, how many is "many"? Just want to know when to watch out for this if it truly is a SC bug.

Comment: Ill try the raw values, have submitted a support ticket to Sitecore. Also, there were only about 15 items max!

Comment: what ended up being the solution?

Answer (score 1):

There was a similar issue in 6.5, but I assumed it would have been addressed in an update. Basically, the issue is a result of presentation setting deltas at the item level incorrectly merging with the standard values presentation settings of the item base template.

I would suggest contacting Sitecore support for a workaround or solution. Reference case #387488 and provide detailed steps to reproduce the issue.